# How can I kill regular part in perl

Tags: perl

I have a lot of the following regular part in my file
I want to kill the word between `TEST1` and `TEST2`
how can I do in perl?

```
TEST1
xxx
xxx
xxx
TEST2
ggg
TEST1
xxx
xxx
TEST2
ggg
```

Comment: Do you want to keep TEST1 and TEST2?

Comment: I want to kill TEST1 and TEST2 , but keep  ggg

Comment: Then amon's answer is what you need

Comment: YES~~It is what I want!!!

Comment: You can't always get what you want. But if you try sometime, you might find, you get what you need.

Comment: Indeed~your suggestion is very useful, and I will keep in mind ^^

Answer (score 3):

Use the flip-flop operator:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless /^TEST1$/ .. /^TEST2/' <<'END'
TEST1
xxx
xxx
xxx
TEST2
ggg
TEST1
xxx
xxx
TEST2
ggg
END
```

Output:

```
ggg
ggg
```